# How to change app version major and minor with gulp-bump?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-bump

I've successfully installed and implemented [**gulp-bump**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump) into my gulp build process now.

However I can only bump up the patch version, which is ok now since that is what we mostly do, and minors every other months or so. However I'd like to be able to, since my legacy code did that.

What I use to do was type this: `V=patch gulp build` or `V=minor gulp build`. I'd use `let env = process.env.V;` To read what the `V` variable was, then pass it through to the `generateNextVersion` logic to determine which version point to update.

The only documentation about minor and major patches in gulp-bump is this:

> Versioning
>   Versioning Used: Semantic
>   String, lowercase
>   MAJOR ("major") version when you make incompatible API changes
>   MINOR ("minor") version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
>
> PATCH ("patch") version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> PRERELEASE ("prerelease") a pre-release version
>
> Version example
>   major: 1.0.0
>   minor: 0.1.0
>   patch: 0.0.2
>   prerelease: 0.0.1-2

```
const getPackageJson = function () {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8'));
};

gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
runSequence(
    'version',                  // Save new version
    'build:del-assets-static',  // Delete old static folder in app/assets
    'build:move-files',         // Move files into new static folder
    // etc ....
});
```

---

```
gulp.task('version', ['bump'], function() {
    // reget package
    var pkg = getPackageJson();
    // increment version
    version = semver.inc(pkg.version, 'patch');
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.red.inverse(' newVer '+version+'                    \n'));
    return generateNextVersion(env);
});

function generateNextVersion(ver) {
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.red.inverse(' ver: '+ver+'                    \n'));
    // var major, minor, patch;
    // var versionArray = lastVersion.split('.');
    //
    // major = parseInt(versionArray[0]);
    // minor = parseInt(versionArray[1]);
    // patch = parseInt(versionArray[2]);
    //
    // switch (ver) {
    //     case 'major' : major += 1; patch = 0; break;
    //     case 'minor' : minor += 1; patch = 0; break;
    //     case 'patch' : patch += 1; break;
    // }
    //
    // version = major + '.' + minor + '.' + patch;
    //
    // if (ver === '' || ver === undefined || ver === null) { version = '0.0.0'; }

    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.blue.bold        ('######################################################     \n'));
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.blue.bold.inverse('           Building Dashboard version '+version+'         \n'));
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.green.italic     ('               All change is detectable                    \n'));
    process.stdout.write(gutil.colors.blue.bold        ('######################################################     \n'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still hoping to get a proper answer to this one, but this is how I'm solving it now:

```
gulp.task('bump', () => {
    gulp.src('./package.json').pipe(bump({ key: "version", type: versionType })).pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('bump:minor', () => {
    versionType = 'minor';
    gulp.src('./package.json').pipe(bump({ key: "version", type: 'minor' })).pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('bump:major', () => {
    versionType = 'major';
    gulp.src('./package.json').pipe(bump({ key: "version", type: 'major' })).pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Just 1 extra step before a minor or major update, but those are special anyways...